# Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n-1}{n+\ln n}$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have the series $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n-1}{n+\ln n}$. Does it converge? What test should I use, the comparison test?

Answer (score 8):

What is $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n-1}{n + \ln n}$? What does that imply about convergence?

Comment: The limit is 1, does that imply that it's divergent?

Comment: That is a very good question. What happens when I try to take an infinite sum of numbers that approach $1$?

Comment: they diverge i think, im not sure...

Comment: Yes, one condition that is necessary for a series $\sum a_n$ to converge is that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$.

Comment: @Mathematicxcz If you're really not sure about that, the best thing you can do right now is read your lecture notes/textbook again...

Answer (score 0):

Observe that : $\ln n < n \Rightarrow \dfrac{n-1}{n+ \ln n} > \dfrac{n-1}{2n} > \dfrac{1}{4} \Rightarrow \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{n-1}{n+\ln n} \geq \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{4} = \infty \Rightarrow \text{ the given series diverges to $\infty$}$.